Как создать список объектов, чтобы атрибуты и методы объекта подсказывались в IDE
Возникла потребность создать список классов на Python. класс используется для хранения данных и должен обладать своими методами, которые будут манипулировать с полями класса.
class B:
    def __init__(self, a:str, b:str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        pass


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_1: str
        self.data_2: str
        self.listB: list[B]

    def foo(self):
        pass


a = A()

b = B("ddd", "rrr")


a.listB.append(b)

при вызове append возникает ошибка: AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'listB'
Не могу понять, что не так. Видимо я слишком засел на C++ и такие действия там проходят на ура.
Я что-то делаю не так, но не могу понять, что именно.
Правлено:
После исправлений:
class B:
    def __init__(self, a:str, b:str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        pass

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_1: str
        self.data_2: str
        self.listB = []

    def foo(self):
        pass


a = A()

b = B("ddd", "rrr")

a.listB.append(b)

vala = a.listB[0].a

В строке vala = a.listB[0].a не выпадает а после точки, как-будто нет поля класса B. Хотя все отрабатывает

Через : вы просто аннотируете тип атрибута, но не создаете его. Если я правильно Вас понял, то попробуйте заменить на self.listB = list(), чтобы создать пустой список и потом иметь возможность добавить в него экземпляр b

@mrgervant Питоничнее (и чуть быстрее) будет self.listB = [] А так да, в конструкторе класса A описаны только типы полей, но не их значения.

да, все верно, так работает. но я хотел добиться другого результата типа, как на С++ 'std::list listMyStruct;' и из получать к конкретному элементу и вызывать поля структуры. Сейчас у меня получается так 'valА = a.listB[0].a', значение получаю верно, но поле a класса B не выпадает в подсказках.

Что-то похоже на приведение к типу класса B, если есть такое

А где именно не выпадает в подсказках? Тот код, про который вы говорите, не приведён в вопросе. Приведите в вопросе код, по которому у вас вопрос и сформулируйте ваши ожидания тоже в тексте вопроса. А то по ходу дела выясняется, что вы спрашиваете не то, что написано у вас в вопросе.

Поля с аннотациями должны быть описаны на уровне класса, а не в методе __init__, тогда IDE будет их видеть. В __init__ нужно делать инициализацию, например присваивание начального значения полю listB.
Пример кода:
class B:
    a: str
    b: str

    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def foo(self):
        pass


class A:
    data_1: str
    data_2: str
    listB: list[B]

    def __init__(self):
        self.listB = []

    def foo(self):
        pass


a = A()
b = B("ddd", "rrr")
a.listB.append(b)

Можно переписать через датаклассы, тогда не нужно будет вручную описывать __init__, в том числе не перекладывать вручную параметры __init__ в одноименные атрибуты, и можно будет прямо при объявлении описать дефолтные значения:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class B:
    a: str
    b: str

    def foo(self):
        pass


@dataclass
class A:
    data_1: str | None = None  # Неизменяемые дефолтные значения можно прописать напрямую
    data_2: str | None = None
    listB: list[B] = field(default_factory=list)  # Изменяемые нужно описывать через default_factory, иначе список будет общим для всех экземпляров класса

    def foo(self):
        pass


a = A()
b = B("ddd", "rrr")
a.listB.append(b)


Спасибо за разъяснения, то что и хотел получить. Видимо я слишком испорчен С++))).

@Артем ну тут более-менее похоже на C++ в итоге получается. Вы же в C++ не объявляете поля класса в конструкторе? Просто C++ на этапе компиляции вас по рукам будет бить, а тут самому в голове нужно держать как должно быть правильно.
